# HTML: input text-transform:capitalize doesn't save capitalize in database

Tags: html, css

I have a form with input text and i set the style to text-transform:capitalize
and when i type in that input i got an uppercase in the first letter of the word.

But when i save it to the database and retrieve it,
all the letters are in lowercase, i have look into my database and the save data is also in lowercase.

why does it save in lowercase, even though i set the input style to text-transform:capitalize;

does `mysqli_real_escape_string` how to do with it?.

Does anyone know why this happens?.

Comment: console the variable before storing it in mysql, if the variable is in capitalize then it must be your db.

Comment: @KalpeshSingh what do you mean by console the variable?

Comment: Do you want it for representation purpose then don't bother what db saves. If you want to save capitalize in db then check the JS/PHP variable where you are saving this input and then adding it to db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try displaying to value of the input when it is sent to the server *before* writing it to DB. I would assume that it is also all lowercase, but confirm that first. If it is all lowercase when the server retrieves the value *before* it is saved to DB then the text-transform property is not preserved when passing the value to the server.

> [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, taking into account the current charset of the connection.

So I would assume escaping the string has nothing to do with it.

In PHP (or other server side languages) you can guarantee that the value is capitalized before writing to DB with functions like: [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)

Comment: tnx for the answer. i found that `ucfirst()` only 1st letter but not by word
example: Peoples park. i want is that 1st letter of every word would capitalize like Peoples Park.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please kindly accept the answer if I was able to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

css doesnt change the value it just change the appearance.. you are confused because in uppercase ... value and appearance both world sort of collide.

to understand why it should not work you can think that .. 
if you just bold the text or underline it.. it is not saved that way right ?

so css just changes the appearance ... you will have to capitalise string again via other programming languages before saving to database

Comment: oh.. .thats why. im sorry. i thought it will be capitalized